# Asociacion de script con elementos creados en el DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Estoy creando una pagina y estoy implementando una simulación de sistema de comentarios utilizando JavaScript y Tailwind para los estilos.

Utilizo este botón para abrir un modal en el que el usuario pueda escribir su nombre, su comentario y tiene un boton para publicarlo:

```
<div class="flex items-center justify-center my-7">
       <button id="comentar" class="bg-blue-600 px-3 py-3 w-[250px] md:w-[400px] rounded-md text-white font-bold hover:bg-blue-500">Añadir comentario</button>
 </div>
```

Y como menciono ese boton esta asociado a un script que abre un modal y este es el script en cuestion:

```
const buttonComment = document.querySelector('#comentar');
const modalComment = document.querySelector('#modal-comentar');
const closeModalComment = document.querySelector('#cerrar-comentario');
const nameComment = document.querySelector('#nombre-comentario');
const commentArea = document.querySelector('#textarea-comentario');
const commentsContainer = document.querySelectorAll('#comments-container');
const sendCommentButton = document.querySelector('#send-comment');

buttonComment.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    modalComment.classList.remove('opacity-0', 'pointer-events-none');
});

closeModalComment.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    modalComment.classList.add('opacity-0', 'pointer-events-none');
    nameComment.value = '';
    commentArea.value = '';
});
```

Al hacer clic en el boton se activa un evento click que abre el modal y en el modal hay un input para el nombre, un textarea para el comentario y un boton para enviar, para el boton de publicar comentario hice este script que es en el tengo problemas:

```
sendCommentButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    const comment = commentArea.value;
    const name = nameComment.value;
    const date = new Date();

    commentsContainer.forEach(container =>{
        const divComment = document.createElement('div');

        divComment.classList.add('flex','justify-center','items-center','mt-5');
        container.append(divComment);

        const bodyComment = document.createElement('div');
        bodyComment.classList.add('w-[320px]', 'md:w-[700px]', 'h-auto', 'text-white');
        divComment.append(bodyComment);

        const headerComment = document.createElement('div');
        headerComment.classList.add('bg-blue-500', 'dark:bg-blue-800', 'w-full', 'h-auto', 'flex');
        bodyComment.append(headerComment);

        const nameCommentSend = document.createElement('p');
        nameCommentSend.classList.add('font-bold', 'text-xl', 'pl-2', 'pt-1', 'pb-1');
        nameCommentSend.textContent = name;
        headerComment.append(nameCommentSend);

        const divSeparator = document.createElement('div');
        divSeparator.classList.add('flex-grow');
        headerComment.append(divSeparator);

        const dateComment = document.createElement('p');
        dateComment.classList.add('font-semibold', 'pr-1', 'pt-1.5', 'text-[14px]');
        dateComment.textContent = `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()}-${date.getDate()} (${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()})`;
        headerComment.append(dateComment);

        const contentComment = document.createElement('div');
        contentComment.classList.add('bg-slate-200', 'dark:bg-gray-600', 'dark:text-white', 'w-full', 'h-auto', 'text-black', 'px-3', 'py-3');

        bodyComment.append(contentComment);

        const textComment = document.createElement('p');
        textComment.textContent = comment;
        contentComment.append(textComment);

        const footerComment = document.createElement('div');
        footerComment.classList.add('bg-white', 'dark:bg-gray-700', 'dark:text-gray-200', 'w-full', 'h-auto', 'text-gray-600', 'flex');
        bodyComment.append(footerComment);

        const replyText = document.createElement('p');
        replyText.classList.add('font-bold', 'px-2', 'py-2', 'cursor-pointer');
        replyText.textContent = "Responder";
        replyText.id = "responder";
        footerComment.append(replyText);

        const heartSeparator = document.createElement('div');
        heartSeparator.classList.add('flex-grow');
        footerComment.append(heartSeparator);

        const iconHeartLabel = document.createElement('label');
        iconHeartLabel.classList.add('icon-heart', 'text-[20px]', 'text-[#aaaaaa]', 'dark:text-[#eceaea]', 'dark:hover:text-[#e66a6a]', 'pr-2', 'pt-2', 'cursor-pointer', 'hover:text-[#d91111]', 'transition-all', 'duration-300');
        iconHeartLabel.id = "heart";

 

   footerComment.append(iconHeartLabel);
})
```

})

Si bien el script funciona bien ya crea correctamente los comentarios pero hay un problema y es que en replyText y iconHeartLabel se les asigna un id que va a estar asociado a otro script en otro archivo la cosa es que el id no se vincula bien con el script externo, pense que era por que el id era incorrecto asi que decidi probar el HTML que arroja el script para comentar en el archivo principal de la pagina y asi queda:

```
<div id="comments-container">
                <div class="flex justify-center items-center mt-5">
                    <div class="w-[320px] md:w-[700px] h-auto text-white">
                        <div class="bg-blue-500 dark:bg-blue-800 w-full h-auto flex">
                            <p class="font-bold text-xl pl-2 pt-1 pb-1">coloco</p>
                            <div class="flex-grow"></div>
                            <p class="font-semibold pr-1 pt-1.5 text-[14px]">hoy</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bg-slate-200 dark:bg-gray-600 dark:text-white w-full h-auto text-black px-3 py-3">
                            <p>asdasdasdsadad</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200 w-full h-auto text-gray-600 flex">
                            <p class="font-bold px-2 py-2 cursor-pointer" id="responder">Responder</p>
                            <div class="flex-grow"></div>
                            <label id="heart" class="icon-heart text-[20px] text-[#aaaaaa] dark:text-[#eceaea] dark:hover:text-[#e66a6a] pr-2 pt-2 cursor-pointer hover:text-[#d91111] transition-all duration-300"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bg-black dark:bg-gray-900 w-full h-2"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Probe su funcionamiento y ahi si que se vincula correctamente el script con el ID, compare en la consola del navegador lo que arroja el script con el HTML que agregue y eran exactamente iguales, mismo id, mismas propiedades solo que no funciona el script.

Y este es el script que se debe ejecutar al hacer click en el texto de responder y en el label icon-heart:

```
const buttonReply = document.querySelectorAll('#responder');
const modalReply = document.querySelector('#modal-responder');
const closeModalReply = document.querySelector('#cerrar-respuesta');
const nameReply = document.querySelector('#nombre-respuesta');
const reply = document.querySelector('#textarea-respuesta');

buttonReply.forEach(button =>{
    button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        modalReply.classList.remove('opacity-0', 'pointer-events-none');
    });

    closeModalReply.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        modalReply.classList.add('opacity-0', 'pointer-events-none');

        nameReply.value = '';
        reply.value = '';
    })
})
```

Alguien sabe a que se debe?

Comment: Hola. Hay algo que deberías tener en cuenta, y es que los IDs de los elementos web no se deberían repetir nunca. En tu caso replyText.id = "responder"; y iconHeartLabel.id = "heart"; pueden dar un ID repetido a un nuevo elemento. Yo en tu lugar añadiría ese valor al classList en vez de setearlo como su ID

Comment: Tal como te han dicho, cuando buscas elementos basándote en un ID, solo encuentras el primero... porque los ID nunca se deberían de repetir. Por otro lado, en vez de buscar todos los elementos y asignarles el click en ese momento, por qué no les añades el `onClick` en el momento que los creas?? Ya que no necesitas buscarlo, ya tienes la referencia al elemento. En vez de `replyText.id = "responder";` puedes en ese momento setearle el eventListener del click... no necesitas andar buscando todos los botones porque los creas tú mismo en código, simplemente seteales lo que necesitas

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas

Comment: Agradezco la solución, implemente lo que mencionaste de agregar el onclick al momento de crearlo